# Iterate through an array of objects and write the data into an excel file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, excel, hashmap, apache-poi

I want to have a class `Employess` from where I create objects with `firstName`, `lastName` and `city`.

I want to iterate through an Employees array, and for each object created to extract the `firstName`, `lastName` and `city` and write it into an Excel file.

My code blocks in the second for block with the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class http.Employees cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Object; (http.Employees is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
> at http.App.main(App.java:64).

I am new to Java and I think that the way I use that HashMap is wrong, but I couldn't figure out how to handle it in the correct way.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Code below:

```
class Employees {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String city;

    public Employees(String firstName, String lastName, String city) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.city = city;
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String excelPath = "C:/Work/01_TSM/java/test.xlsx";

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelPath));

//      create workbook object
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

//      create spreadsheet object
        XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);

//       create row object
        XSSFRow row;

//       This data needs to be written in (Object[])
        HashMap<Integer, Object> employeeData = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();

        Employees employee1 = new Employees("John", "Smith", "CT");
        Employees employee2 = new Employees("Jane", "Doe", "O");
        Employees[] employees = { employee1, employee2 };

//       Insert data
        for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            employeeData.put(i, employees[i]);
        }
        ;

        Set<Integer> keyid = employeeData.keySet();

        int rowid = 1;

//       writing the data into the sheets
        for (Integer key : keyid) {
            row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);

            // here the code breaks
            Object[] objectArr = (Object[]) employeeData.get(key);
            int cellid = 0;
            
            
            for (Object obj : objectArr) {

                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            }
        }

//       writing the workbook into the file
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Work/01_TSM/java/test.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, why don't you just write to a csv file (which will open in Excel)? Class names should be [singular](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions) in most cases btw

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code lies in the way you retrieve an `Employees` from the `HashMap`. In fact, your `employeeData` is defined as a `HashMap` with `Integer` keys and `Object` values (i.e. your `Employees`). When you perform a `map.get(key)`, the method returns an `Object`, specifically an `Employees`, not an `Object[]`; thus the `ClassCastException`.

Besides, `HashMap` is a generic class. This means that the type parameters K and V, representing the data types of your keys and values, can be specified with proper type arguments. In your case, it will be a better fit to use `Employees` as the data type for your values. In fact, `Object` is far too generic, it forces you to resort to casting and losing one of the many benefits of generics.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Lastly, It doesn't seem like a `HashMap` is actually needed for the code you've written. In fact, you could simplify it by using an array of `Employees`. Here I'll leave both implementations which rely on getter methods in your `Employees` class:

##### HashMap Implementation

```
String pathFileExcel = "C:/Work/01_TSM/java/test.xlsx";

//Creating a workbook
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

//Making sure a spreadSheet exsists before retrieving it
if (workbook.getNumberOfSheets() == 0) {
    workbook.createSheet();
}
XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//Creating a map
Map<Integer, Employees> employeeMap = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
        0, new Employees("John", "Smith", "CT"),
        1, new Employees("Jane", "Doe", "O")
));

int rowNum = 0;

//writing the data into the sheets
for (Integer key : employeeMap.keySet()) {
    XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowNum++);

    Employees emp = employeeMap.get(key);

    Cell cellFirstName = row.createCell(0);
    cellFirstName.setCellValue((emp.getFirstName()));

    Cell cellLastName = row.createCell(1);
    cellLastName.setCellValue((emp.getLastName()));

    Cell cellCity = row.createCell(2);
    cellCity.setCellValue((emp.getCity()));
}

//the try-with automatically closes the connection once exited the try block
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pathFileExcel);) {
    workbook.write(out);
}
```

##### Array of Employees Implementation

```
String pathFileExcel = "C:/Work/01_TSM/java/test.xlsx";

//Creating a workbook
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

//Making sure a spreadSheet exsists before retrieving it
if (workbook.getNumberOfSheets() == 0) {
    workbook.createSheet();
}
XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//Creating an array
Employees[] vetEmp = new Employees[]{
        new Employees("John", "Smith", "CT"),
        new Employees("Jane", "Doe", "O")
};

int rowNum = 0;

//writing the data into the sheets
for (Employees emp : vetEmp) {
    XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowNum++);

    Cell cellFirstName = row.createCell(0);
    cellFirstName.setCellValue((emp.getFirstName()));

    Cell cellLastName = row.createCell(1);
    cellLastName.setCellValue((emp.getLastName()));

    Cell cellCity = row.createCell(2);
    cellCity.setCellValue((emp.getCity()));
}

//the try-with automatically closes the connection once exited the try block
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pathFileExcel);) {
    workbook.write(out);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation and the examples provided sir!

Answer (score 0):

The value is not an array of objects, but objects of type 'Employees' so you cannot cast it to an array:

```
        Object[] objectArr = (Object[]) employeeData.get(key);
        int cellid = 0;
        
        
        for (Object obj : objectArr) {

            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
            cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
        }
```

EDIT: i think this may be what you are trying to achieve:

```
    HashMap<Integer, Object> employeeData = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();

    Employees employee1 = new Employees("John", "Smith", "CT");
    Employees employee2 = new Employees("Jane", "Doe", "O");
    Employees[] employees = { employee1, employee2 };

    for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        employeeData.put(i, employees[i]);
    }

    Set<Integer> keyid = employeeData.keySet();
    int rowid = 1;
    for (Integer key : keyid) {
        row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);

        // here the code breaks
        Employees employee = (Employees)employeeData.get(key);
        for (int cellid = 0; cellid < 3; cellid++)
        {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellid++):
            if (cellid == 0)
            {
                cell.setCellValue(employee.firstName);
            }
            else if(cellid == 1)
            {
                cell.setCellValue(employee.lastName);
            }
            else if(cellid == 2)
            {
                cell.setCellValue(employee.city);
            }
        }
```

Comment: That wouldn't compile but in any case, why would two pieces of data be placed in the same cell?

Comment: It's pseudocode, but why wouldn't it compile? I don't have your exact model, but i can tell it has a first and last name. When you make it a string, it's no longer two values but just ONE string.. so one value. Your problem is the typecast of an object to an object of which type it is not.

Comment: Notice the line where you put the comment '// here the code breaks'. Change the line to the one i put in and you see the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example you can use. Pass the full path to the output file as an argument to the program:

```
package xlsconv;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;

public class Beans2Sheet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Beans2Sheet b2s = new Beans2Sheet();
            Employee[] emps = new Employee[] {
                new Employee("John", "Doe", "Kansas City"),
                new Employee("John", "Doe", "New York City")
            };
            b2s.beans2Sheet(emps, Paths.get(args[0]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void beans2Sheet(Employee[] employees, Path outputPath) throws IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet();

        for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < employees.length; rowNum++) {

            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
            String[] fields = employees[rowNum].toFields();
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(i);
                cell.setCellValue(fields[i]);
            }
        }

        try (OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(outputPath))) {
            workBook.write(out);
        }
    }

}
```

This uses a little convenience method in class `Employee` that returns the class fields as an array:

```
public String[] toFields() {
    return new String[] { firstName, lastName, city };
}
```

Comment: This does not explain why his code crashes

Comment: But you've *already* done that ..?